# SQLite - Output count of all records per day including days with 0 records

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 database maintained on an AWS exchange that is regularly updated by a Python script. One of the things it tracks is when any team generates a new post for a given topic. The entries look something like this:

| id | client | team | date | industry | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 895 | acme industries | blueteam | 2022-06-30 | construction | springfield |

I'm trying to create a table that shows me how many entries for `construction` occur each day. Right now, the entries with data populate, but they exclude dates with no entries. For example, if I search for just

```
SELECT date, count(id) as num_records
from mytable
WHERE industry = "construction"
group by date
order by date asc
```

I'll get results that looks like this:

| date | num_records |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-04-01 | 3 |
| 2022-04-04 | 1 |

How can I make sqlite output like this:

| date | num_records |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-04-02 | 3 |
| 2022-04-02 | 0 |
| 2022-04-03 | 0 |
| 2022-04-04 | 1 |

I'm trying to generate some graphs from this data and need to be able to include all dates for the target timeframe.

EDIT/UPDATE:
The table does not already include every date; it only includes dates relevant to an entry. If no team posts work on a day, the `date` column will jump from day 1 (e.g. 2022-04-01) to day 3 (2022-04-03).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your "*mytable*" table contains all dates you need as an assumption, you can first select all of your dates, then apply a [`LEFT JOIN`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-left-join/) to your own query, and map all resulting NULL values for the "*num_records*" field to "0" using the [`COALESCE`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-coalesce/) function.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT date, 
           COUNT(id) AS num_records
    FROM mytable
    WHERE industry = "construction"
    GROUP BY date
    ORDER BY date
)
SELECT dates.date, 
       COALESCE(cte.num_records, 0) AS num_records
FROM      (SELECT date FROM mytable) dates
LEFT JOIN cte
       ON dates.date = cte.date
```

Comment: `mytable` does not include all dates. It only includes dates when data was entered. So if no work is done over the weekend, there won't be any entries with those weekend days in the `date` column.

Comment: Then you need to generate a list of all potential days as a table, and use its alias name in place of "*mytable*" as a replacement inside `FROM      (SELECT date FROM mytable) dates`. That is the only way you can do this.

Comment: That did the trick. I wish there was a way to generate the dates on the fly, so I don't have to come back and add dates to another table, but this does this trick for at least the next 1338 days (:laugh:) until I have to make changes.